# Eclipselink: how to add it to local repository

Tags: git, maven, repository, eclipselink

```
GIT clone and checkout eclipselink.runtime
git clone https://.../eclipselink.runtime.git
git checkout -b testing tag/2.6.5
```

The version in POM.xml is `<version>2.6.5-SNAPSHOT</version>` ???

Tried to add eclipselink.jar into local repository:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=eclipselink.jar 
 -DgroupId=org/eclipse/persistence -DartifactId=eclipselink 
 -Dversion=2.6.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Is there an ant/maven target for installing eclipselink jar into local repository?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add eclipse link to your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```